# Customize color for each show page - ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

We have several organizations each with a .show.html.erb page. We'd like to enable organizations to customize the color of their page.

In our schema we have:

```
create_table "organizations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "theme"
end
```

I tried adding the following to our 'layouts/application.html.erb' page to enable this customization (works locally, but not in production):

```
<style media="screen">
  .theme {
    background: #<%= @organization.theme %> !important;
  }
</style>
```

I'm pretty new to Rails...am I even thinking about this correctly? Does anyone have any ideas on a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a `yield` block to accomplish this.

In `layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<style media="screen">
  .theme {
    background: #<%= content_for?(:theme) ? yield(:theme) : default_theme %> !important;
  }
</style>
```

In each view:

```
<% content_for :theme, @organization.theme %>
```

See the docs of understanding `yield`:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

More on `content_for`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for